# Javascript - Array is of type object and failing at .push directly after declaration of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

```
const audio = connection.receiver.createStream(message, { mode: 'pcm', end: 'manual' });    
var testingArr = new Array();
    audio.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(Array.isArray(testingArr)); //output: false
      testingArr.push(data);
    });
```

The body here shows testingArr as not of type array
How is this happening?

I am looking to add the new data to the array as it comes in over a few seconds so I can decrypt it into text strings.

I have also tried  var testingArr = [], and encountered the same issue

The Error I get when I attempt to run this script:

```
TypeError: testingArr.push is not a function
    at Decoder.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Your code looks good. You need to know that `typeof` doesn't always tell you what you want to know. You also need to know that if it's not a scalar value (string, number, boolean, null, symbol), then the item IS an object - everything in JS is an object, even functions and arrays. The following expression is always true: `typeof [] === 'object'`. You can use `Array.isArray(testingArr)` to check if something is actually an array or not.

Comment: @RyanWheale Thank you, ill adjust my console log, however, I am getting a typeof error when attempting to use .push. I will add that to my original post

Comment: Example is out of context

Comment: @AbsentmindedInsanity That code should work. Isn't there any part of the code assigning to `testingArr` (`testingArr = ...`)?

Comment: check that you do not altered `testingArr` somehow later on. Use `const` instead of `var`

Comment: Ah I am a fool. Way farther down in the script I assigned testingArr to another value by accident outside of the async context. Marking this as closed. Thank you all for your time

Comment: and this is why you should make that array `const` (or `let`) so that duplicate reassignments are detected...

Comment: @Alnitak actually `let` will allow you to alter variable later on, if you'll do this without declaring `let` again.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally set testingArr to another value outside of the async process farther down in the script.